# has_category WordPress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I would like to check in the Wordpress loop for a category named Hyperlink and Quotes because I will not display those categories.

I checked the Wordpress site, but I am still stuck. What I got so far:

```
has_category(Hyperlink, Quotes);    --> This doesn't work!

has_category(array(Hyperlinks, Quotes); );    --> This doesn't work either!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category

It looks like the proper syntax would be `has_category('Hyperlink')`. I'm not sure if you left the quotes out by mistake or if you didn't know they needed to be there. They need to be there.

Also, it looks like `has_category(array('Hyperlinks', 'Quotes'));` would work as well.

HTH,

=C=